# Where or how do I tell CakePHP (2.x) to ignore the Views in a database, so that it works only with the Tables?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a CakePHP 2.x app running with a MySQL database.

Another developer, for another purpose in another app (In Asp.Net) created some MySQL Views in the database itself.

These Views seem to be confusing for my CakePHP app, because it is taking them as tables and messing some things up in terms of keys, relationships, etc.

Is there a way or place for me to tell my CakePHP app that it needs not to worry about these Views and just keep working with the Tables as it always had before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After continued reading on how CakePHP works with the MySQL database and also studying the MySQL syntaxes, I came up with the solution below and it worked. I post it here for others who may need it and/or for more experienced developers to post on rather or not this is a good idea.

I found the file where CakePHP grabs the tables from the database:

/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php

I found the line of code that does this job:

`$result = $this->_execute('SHOW TABLES FROM ' . $this->name($this->config['database']));`

Notice the MySQL statement, especifically:

`'SHOW TABLES FROM ' . $this->name($this->config['database'])`

Reading the `SHOW TABLES` documentation, I learned what it does and its syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html

So, I changed the statement to:

`'SHOW FULL TABLES FROM ' . $this->name($this->config['database']) . ' WHERE Table_Type != "VIEW"'`

Basically:

1. I changed `SHOW TABLES` to `SHOW FULL TABLES` so that it would include the second column which holds `BASE TABLE` for regular tables and `VIEW` for views.
2. Then, I used this second column information in the `WHERE` statement that I added: `WHERE Table_Type != "VIEW"'` to filter views out of the results.

The new final line is:

`$result = $this->_execute('SHOW FULL TABLES FROM ' . $this->name($this->config['database']) . ' WHERE Table_Type != "VIEW"' );`

The app seems to be working perfectly again!

Answer (score 0):

For every table model your CakePHP app is using, define the `table` attribute

If a table dont have a `Model` associated with, you have to create it

```
class Somemodel extends AppModel{

    public $table = "somemodels";

}
```

Comment: So that's the best way to go about it? Declare each Model's table one by one? I can't just add some config or cmd code somewhere that says ignore Views?

Comment: would you show me what kind of confusion your app is having. cause actually this situation is strange, and i have been working with tables my app doesn't use and everything is working just fine

Comment: So, there have always been tables this app didn't use. That was ok. The problem is that the Views this other person made were to relate things differently for his end, which then meant CakePHP was reading relationships differently also. One of these Views changes an association directly. I have found something that seems to work. I'm about to post it and hopefully the feedback will be that it's ok.